How to detect which particular configuration property has changed in Android device when using a BroadcastReceiver
Here is my code for the BroadcastReceiver class:
class TWOSBroadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver () {

override fun onReceive (context: Context?, pIntent: Intent?)
{
    when (pIntent!!.action) {

        Intent.ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED -> {

            context!!.resources.configuration.locales
            context.resources.configuration.uiMode
            context.resources.configuration.orientation
        }
    }
}
}

As I change the system language, orientation, or theme it will trigger the same action i.e. ACTION_CONFIGURATION_CHANGED, then how to identify which of the following properties has changed as I want to perform different action based on if language, orientation, or theme has changed.
Do I need to store the previous configuration and compare or is there any other way to do the same?

Yes, it looks like the only way to determine which specific property has changed is to save the previous configuration and compare the fields you are interested in.
